# auto read width/height of image and resize another

Tags: php, html, css, image

I just made a website that the user can upload an image, the image gets stored on the database and the image gets displayed with a grid on top of it,
its like an image on top of another image, the real question here is : how can I auto resize the "grid image" to fit the same size of the image that the user uploaded? is it possible?

here is some part of the code/css

how I print the image:

```
<div id="content">
<img class="imgupl" src="../susana/uploads/images/<?php echo $image; ?>.<?php echo $extension; ?>"/>
<img class="imggrid" src="../susana/media/images/grid1920.png">
</div>
```

the css:

```
 #content { 
 float: left; position: relative; 
 }

 .imgupl { 
 position:absolute; 
 z-index: 1; 
 } 
 .imggrid { 
 position:absolute; 
 z-index: 3; 
 }
```

Comment: How about uploading cropped image and then using that image ?

Comment: Are you able to provide a https://jsfiddle.net/ with the HTML code produced so we can view what's happening?

Comment: What about css like `.imggrid { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`? Because parent container `position: relative;` it should work... No?

Comment: Im not good using jsfiddle, but i can show you a printscreen of how it is at the moment: http://s18.postimg.org/oekv8d1qx/image2222.png , as you can see, the grid doesn't fit the uploaded image...

Comment: try this css :  `.imgupl {position:relative;z-index: 1;} .imggrid { position:absolute; top:0px;left:0px;z-index: 3;width:100%;height:100%;}`